# Access a specific pod from external

Tags: kubernetes

We have an old service discovery system that requires processes to register its ip:port during startup. On a kubernetes cluster, we exposed a service that enables NodePort. The processes within container can register to the old system with their Pod Ip:port + HostIp. For the clients within the same kubernetes cluster, they should be able to connect to the right process via specific Pod Ip:port. For an external client, it knows the HostIp+NodePort and the specific Pod Ip:port, is there an efficient way to route the client’s request to the specific Pod? Running a proxy on each node to route the traffic (nodeport -> pod) seems inefficient due to additional proxy layer.

Comment: Hi @user221074 , did you find a satisfactory solution for this? Thnx

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean you don't want to add a Service of type [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport) as for your case that seems like an additional proxy layer. I can see how it is an additional layer in your case. Typically Kubernetes would be doing the orchestration and the Service would be part of the service-discovery mechanism. It sounds like you could use [hostPort](http://alesnosek.com/blog/2017/02/14/accessing-kubernetes-pods-from-outside-of-the-cluster/). But if you do go this route you should be aware it's [not suggested practice](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/) as Kubernetes is intended for orchestration.

Comment: I used NodePort-service since I want the external request to be able to go to the node that runs a couple of pods.  And the iptables (NodePort) is kernel-level routing, I think that's efficient. hostPort might not be expected since it doesn't allow multiple pods (w/ same port) on a node.

Comment: Cool, makes sense. Thanks

Comment: @user221074 did you find a satisfactory solution for this? Thnx